# How to get any file from ftp server and put it into specific local folder with bash?

Tags: ftp

I am stuck on this :(. I want to download a file from a frp server and put in into a specific folder, but I only manage to download it...

Conection:

```
ftp ftp.rediris.es
```

Get file:

```
get "fileName"
```

I've tried something like:

```
get "fileName" C/Images
```

but it doesn't really work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work

```
get "fileName" "C:\Images\fileName"
```

You can replace "C:\Images\" with whatever location you want as long as you put the correct and full path name. The above example assumes you are downloading to a Windows machine. On a UNIX/Linux machine the following example would look like below

```
get "fileName" "/user/Images/fileName"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `get "fileName" "F:\Folder"` gives me an error like this _Error opening local file F:\Folder_ on windows.

Comment: You need to specify the filename also like `F:\Folder\filename`. Also did you actually check from the command-line that this folder already exists and you have permissions to create files in it?

Comment: ok, it works now.
I forget to put the _fileName_ after the route. Thank you guys :D